# Scheduling problem in chapter 3 of The Design of Approximation Algorithms by David P. Williamson and David B. Shmoys

Tags: algorithms

Suppose we have $m$ machines and $n$ jobs that can start immediately, and we want to distribute jobs to minimize the longest processing time among all machines. For any $\epsilon=1/k$ for some integer $k$, if we are sure all jobs have processing time more than $\epsilon T$ where $T$ is the upper bound for the optimal longest processing time and are able to find optimal solution with processing times of all jobs rounded down to integer multiples of $\epsilon^2T$, then we are able to say the job distribution we have solved is no more than $(1+\epsilon)T$. However, I am not sure if this holds when $1/\epsilon$ is not an integer. I don't know if it is covered somewhere in the textbook so I would appreciate a lot if anyone can point out the part where it is explained.

For the integer case, all jobs take time more than $\epsilon T$ which is an integer multiple of $\epsilon^2T$, so the rounded times are at least $\epsilon T$, and due to rounding, in our solution every machine takes less than $1/\epsilon$ jobs. The longest time in the rounded-down case is at most $T$, and without rounding it should be less than $$T+\frac{\epsilon^2T}{\epsilon}=T(1+\epsilon).$$ However in the non-integer case we cannot guarantee that the rounded time is still at least $\epsilon T$. The bound $L$ I can get is $$\frac{L}{\epsilon T}\epsilon^2T>L-T\Rightarrow L<\frac{T}{1-\epsilon}.$$ Is there a way to prove the bound $1+\epsilon$ or find a counter-example to this bound? Thanks for any contribution to this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $1/\epsilon=a-b$ where $a=\lceil1/\epsilon\rceil$, and $b$ is small enough to make $\lfloor(a-b)^2\rfloor=a^2-1$, then $\lfloor T\rfloor=\epsilon^2T(a^2-1)$. If the jobs are $a+1$ jobs with time close to but less than $a\epsilon^2T$(which will be rounded down to $(a-1)\epsilon^2T$), one job with time $T$, and total number of machines $m=3$, then an optimal solution when job times are rounded down could be to assign all $a+1$ jobs with time around $a\epsilon^2T$ to a machine and the job with time $T$ to another. In this case the actual largest load is about $$a(a+1)\epsilon^2T>1/\epsilon(1/\epsilon+1)\epsilon^2T=(1+\epsilon)T,$$ thus proving the bound $1+\epsilon$ incorrect when $1/\epsilon$ is not an integer. The optimality of $T$ is guaranteed by making $a$ large. In this case an optimal solution could be to assign the job with time $T$ to a machine and split the rest almost equally between two machines, with one machine taking at most one more job than the other. In this case the optimal longest workload is $T$.